# MVC3 Ap in Visual Studio 2010- Changed to use Local IIS Web Server and can not get it back to VS dev server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I changed from running Use Visual Studio Development Server to Local IIS Web Server becasue I read it would create the virtual directories properly - it did not - once I navigate out of the account area I get
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Requested URL
https://localhost:443/xxx/Index

Physical Path
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\xxx\Index

I have been googling and trying to get it to work, but can not and can no longer debug - Now I am trying to change it back and it keeps starting in Local IIS Web.  I have HOSED myself and don't know where to go from here.
Thank you

Comment: what specifically are you trying to get to, /home/controller?  do you have a certificate installed locally (otherwise you cant use https) also you don't need to specify 443, you are already specifying ssl via HTTPS://

Comment: I do have a certificate installed.  I am able to login and land on localhost/VirtualDirectory/Account/Index.  When I click on any navigation, I get the error.  I am not sure where the 443 comes from, other than maybe InputEndpoint. It doesn't show in the URL until the error.

Comment: Are you saying the certificate may be improperly installed locally?  I apologize, this is my first SSL site and I am so confused, I am not sure what info to give.  Thx

Comment: try to manually enter in a new URL, for ex. https://localhost/virtual/controller/action instead of clicking on a link. Or if you mouse over your link, whats it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of not leaving questions unanswered,  I tried all of the suggestions above, and many more, and got nowhere.  I was in an early phase at the time, and I had to move on, so I ended up creating a new solution, and porting things over.  Not the best idea, but I had to go forward, and I had taken enough time.  It is still living on my machine, and I plan to go back and figure it out at some point.  Hopefully, I'll have more understanding and will be able to post what I did wrong so someone else can save some time.  Thanks all for attempting.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of getting back to using the VS web server you should just need to:

1. Right click on the web project in VS
2. Selection properties
3. Go to the web tab
4. Select "use visual studio web server" radio button